# Rust panic only when launch by LLDB in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, lldb, rust-cargo

Summary:

- Run `cargo build` and `cargo run` in vscode terminal window => Success
- Run created exe file in the vscode terminal window after `cargo build` my self => Success
- Build cargo from in `tasks.json` => Success
- Debugging by LLDB launch in `launch.json` => **Failed**
- Debugging by LLDB attch in `launch.json` after run my self => Success

Currently, I just ran the following example in vscode:

```rust
extern crate winapi;

use winapi::shared::windef::*;
use winapi::shared::minwindef::*;
use winapi::um::winuser::*;
use winapi::um::wingdi::*;
use winapi::um::libloaderapi::*;

use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn to_wstring(s : &str) -> Vec<u16> {
    OsStr::new( s ).encode_wide().chain( std::iter::once( 0 ) ).collect()
}

pub unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(hwnd : HWND, msg : UINT, wparam : WPARAM, lparam : LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    if msg == WM_DESTROY {
        PostQuitMessage( 0 );
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProcW( hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam );
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let wc = WNDCLASSEXW {
            cbSize : std::mem::size_of::< WNDCLASSEXW >() as UINT,
            style : CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS,
            lpfnWndProc : Some( window_proc ),
            cbClsExtra : 0,
            cbWndExtra : 0,
            hInstance : GetModuleHandleW( std::ptr::null_mut() ) as HINSTANCE,
            hIcon : std::ptr::null_mut(),
            hCursor : LoadCursorW( std::ptr::null_mut(), IDC_ARROW ),
            hbrBackground : GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH as i32 ) as HBRUSH,
            lpszMenuName : std::ptr::null_mut(),
            lpszClassName : to_wstring( "rust_window_class" ).as_ptr(),
            hIconSm : std::ptr::null_mut()
        };
        if RegisterClassExW( &wc ) == 0 {
            panic!( "RegisterClassEx failed" );
        }

        let hwnd = CreateWindowExW( 
            0, wc.lpszClassName, to_wstring( "Rust Window" ).as_ptr(), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            0, 0, 640, 480, std::ptr::null_mut(), std::ptr::null_mut(), wc.hInstance, std::ptr::null_mut()
        );
        if hwnd == std::ptr::null_mut() {
            panic!( "CreateWindowEx failed" );
        }

        ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );

        let mut msg = MSG {
            hwnd : std::ptr::null_mut(),
            message : 0,
            wParam : 0,
            lParam : 0,
            time : 0,
            pt : POINT{ x : 0, y : 0 },
        };
        loop {
            let res = GetMessageW( &mut msg, std::ptr::null_mut(), 0, 0 );
            if res == 0 || res == -1 {
                break;
            }

            DispatchMessageW( &msg );
        }
    }
}
```

It ran fine and windows worked fine.
However, debugging using lldb in vscode failed.

I used the vscode rust extension to create the following syntax for `launch.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Debug executable 'rust-ex'",
  "cargo": {
      "args": [
          "build",
          "--bin=rust-ex",
          "--package=rust-ex"
      ],
      "filter": {
          "name": "rust-ex",
          "kind": "bin"
      }
  },
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

For reference, my project name is "rust-ex".

This `launch.json` entry failed to run the example in the link(winapi) above

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'CreateWindowEx failed', src\main.rs:51:13
```

This `launch.json` entry worked fine for the hello world example.

And build the winapi example from cargo directly in the terminal window, and run the exe directly, both work well.

This time, using the vscode LLDB extension, the following syntax was created:

```json
{
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "test",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/rust-ex.exe",
  "args": [],
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

This also caused the same error.

This time, using the vscode LLDB extension, the following syntax was created:

```json
{
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "pid": "${command:pickMyProcess}"
},
```

This works fine after I run it myself. (with select pid my self)

So this time I added the following to tasks.json:

```json
{
  "label": "rust test",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "start",
  "args": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/rust-ex.exe"
  ]
}
```

Then, in launch.json , I tried:

```json
{
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach Test",
  "preLaunchTask": "rust test",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/target/debug/rust-ex.exe"
},
```

This works very well as I intended.

Why does the same code panic when only launch by LLDB?

Comment: I had some similar issues between using `cargo run` vs calling the executable directly on linux. If I remember correctly, issue was that `cargo` loaded some shared library when launching the program. The program would then load a different shared library using `libloading` which required the library that had been loaded by `cargo`, but was unable to find it on its own. The issue may be related to your linker or environment variables not be being able to find something when launched with `lldb`

Answer (score 1):

You have at least one UB in your program - the vector containing window class name gets freed before you call CreateWindowExW.  You should keep that object alive until you are done using the string.